# Creating a button

Tags: android, button

I am trying to create a button which would start the randomGenerator.

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(9);
    String wordList[] = new String[9];
    {
        wordList[0] = "Mexican";
        wordList[1] = "American";
        wordList[2] = "Barbeque";
        wordList[3] = "Chinese";
        wordList[4] = "Indian";
        wordList[5] = "Italian";
        wordList[6] = "Thai";
        wordList[7] = "Viatnamese";
        wordList[8] = "Middle Eastern";

    }


 String wordToDisplay = wordList[randomInt];
```

Here's my layout, I have already created my button and labeled it. Just not sure how to proceed from here.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"

        tools:context=".ImHungry" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/button1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

```
Button mButton; 
TextView mTextView;
String wordList[] = new String[9];


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 
mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
mButton.setOnClickListener(onClick); 


    {
        wordList[0] = "Mexican";
        wordList[1] = "American";
        wordList[2] = "Barbeque";
        wordList[3] = "Chinese";
        wordList[4] = "Indian";
        wordList[5] = "Italian";
        wordList[6] = "Thai";
        wordList[7] = "Viatnamese";
        wordList[8] = "Middle Eastern";

    }

    }



    private View.OnClickListener onClick= new View.OnClickListener() {
            // @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
         int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(9);
         String wordToDisplay = wordList[randomInt];
        mTextView.setText(wordToDisplay);
        }

    };
```

***NOTE :*** In your code, your TextView is missing the id attribute. Make sure you do add it.

```
<TextView
    android:id="textview1"
...
```

Comment: what exactly is the "..." supposed to replace?

Comment: updated answer. Note :Please have a look at the tutorial I suggested you.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, You should add this to your `onCreate()`:

```
     final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
             Random randomGenerator = new Random();
             int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(9);
             String wordToDisplay = wordList[randomInt];

             // display in TextView
             TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
             tv.setText(wordToDisplay);
         }
     });
```

And add `android:id="textview1"` to your TextView xml.

Comment: thanks! and how exactly would I display this into the textview?

Comment: Why don't you try looking at some documentation and accepting this, or any of the other answers

Comment: Updated! And you should follow @Eliezer suggestions to build your knowledge solidly :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

Add `android:onClick="randomGenerator"` to your button attribute.  Then in your activity. 
make a function that will be called when your button is clicked. (I assumed that you wanted to do your random generation code when the button is clicked.)

```
public void randomGenerator(View view){

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(9);
    String wordList[] = new String[9];
    {
        wordList[0] = "Mexican";
        wordList[1] = "American";
        wordList[2] = "Barbeque";
        wordList[3] = "Chinese";
        wordList[4] = "Indian";
        wordList[5] = "Italian";
        wordList[6] = "Thai";
        wordList[7] = "Viatnamese";
        wordList[8] = "Middle Eastern";

    }

    String wordToDisplay = wordList[randomInt];

}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in the onCreate method:

```
Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        tv.setText(wordToDisplay);
        }
    });
```

And don't forget to set an id in the TextView. i.e.

```
<TextView
    android:id="textview1"
...
```